# WordPress Async HTTP Requests

Tags: wordpress, http, asynchronous

I'm looking for more information on "async" HTTP requests using WordPress' `wp_remote_request` function. **Specifically, whether or not they are killed when the requests/process ends but the HTTP request has not finished.**

I have a HTTP request which works as intended, here's an example request for context:

```php
wp_remote_request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/123', [
    'method' => 'GET',
    'blocking' => false
]);
```

Notice the `blocking` parameter, I can't find much documentation on it so I will just describe it as signaling we do not care about the response from the URL, we only want to send the request.